# How can I represent that all element has some property?

Tags: graph-theory

I want to represent mathematically that all elements $v \in V$ has $x$ and $y$ properties.

I tried:

> Consider a graph $G=(V,E)$ where $\forall v \in V(G) \Rightarrow x[v] \in \mathbb{R} \space|\space y[v] \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is it correct?

Comment: There is no reason to write $V(G)$. $V$ is used for the definition of $G$, so it is assumed to be unambiguously defined.

Comment: You are not expressing the $v$ "has properties" $x$ and $y$. You are expressing that the properties $x$ and $y$ of $v$ are real numbers. I'd rather denote $v_x,v_y$ or $v.x,v.y$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ and $y$ are predicates with one variable each, then $\forall v\in V(G): x(v)\wedge y(v)$ or $\forall v: v\in V(G)\Rightarrow x(v)\wedge y(v)$.

Comment: $\forall v\in V$, not $\forall v\in G$...

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are numeric values (coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no (standard) formal way to state explicitly that a variable "has such and such properties". Usually, this is simply explained or introduced in a "Notation" section.